# How to show the copyright symbol in a Android dialog?

Tags: android

I have to show copyright symbol: © in the message of an AlertDialog. I set a string value with the copyright symbol in res/string. But the symbol is shown as a question mark when the dialog opens. How can I correctly show the copyright symbol in the dialog. Thanks.

Comment: Does the font that's used to display the dialog include the copyright symbol?

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows? Do other special characters like umlauts show up right? Also (this may not work, I didn't test it) - what happens when you set the text of your dialog to Html.fromHtml("&copy; 2010 Test")?

Comment: how about i need to read it in the raw xml file?

Answer (score 126):

You can also use the Unicode character for this: "\u00A9 2010 Test"

Comment: awesome! I was even able to add the less than or equal to symbol this way:  **<string name="test_string" formatted="false">apostrophe\' newline\n less than or equal to\u2264 percent%</string>**

Comment: This worked for me as well. Can we mark this as the correct answer based on the positive response it has received?

Answer (score 88):

Use `&#169;` to write © in a String resource:

`Copyright &#169; Acme Industries, Inc`

becomes

Copyright © Acme Industries, Inc

Comment: @Erick your method works in a String applied directly to the View. This works for string resources.

Answer (score 38):

Write it this way:

```
> String copyright = "Copyright \u00a9 2013, ajdeguzman";
```

Answer (score 5):

Use  "\u00a9" it is working exactly as required.

Answer (score 0):

very simple, try adding \ before @