# print copyright symbol in TextView

Tags: java, android

I am parsing the xml which has copyright symbol in some tag which i'm getting as String and displaying it on TextView. But instead of symbol it is printing #174; . Can anyone tell that how can I print appropriate symbol.

EDIT: It is like this in xml **Raghav©** and i want to display it like this, but it is displaying only **#174;**

Comment: check this    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242251/how-to-show-copyright-symbol-in-dialog

Comment: check if the actual text is xml is #174; or &#174;. If the former, add the &.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try the unicode symbol "\u00a9" and see if it works

Comment: don't think it will. \u notation is for java files to be compiled, not xml.

Comment: "\u00a9" works for me in java. But i need tick mark. for that i am used "\u2713" but nothing display. any one  guide me please

Answer (score 1):

Try the copyright symbol using string '&#169', it will surely help you in accessing your xml like this- **Raghav©**.